# Or die не работает

Tags: php

Есть вот такой запрос.

```
$tb = $b->listtransactions($user)or die("Server is currently unavailable:");
```

При ошибке выполнения запроса ошибка не выводится. 
Может как то другим способом выводить?

Comment: а что возвращает listtransactions() когда ошибка ? думается мне что пустой массив. в таком случае просто проверяйте

     count($tb) or die("Oh");

Comment: >> $b->listtransactions($user)or die("Server is currently unavailable:");

между ($user) и or поставьте пробел

Comment: Неее. Массив не возвращает. Точнее вобще ничего не возвращает. Страница дальше не подгружается а ошибка пишется в бд. 
$b - подключение к другому серверу. 
И вот подключения если нет - тогда нужно выводить ошибку. На и на переменной $b поставил тоже or die - ничего не выводится. 
Я так думаю, что нужно разрешить дальше грузить страницу если нет подключения. 
Вопрос тогда еще один - как?=)

Comment: А варнинги и эрроры на вывод выставить никак, и уже там посмотреть, что именно пишет? 
Смотрите журнал ошибок на сервере и скажите, что пишет

Comment: @RattleSneyk там видимо исключение где-то по дороге, тогда вам сюда:

http://php.net//manual/ru/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что после or выполниться, только в случае, если `$b->listtransactions($user)` вернет эквивалент `false`. В вашем случае, скорее все он выбрасыает эксэпшн и умирает ничего не возвращая

Попробуйте так:

```
try {
    $b->listtransactions($user);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Server is currently unavailable:';
    // echo $e->message # Вывод сообщения об ошибке
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.